# I am trying to store the Authorization Token fetched from the Rest API and then use it in the headers of other API calls in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-widget

As the title of the problem explains most of it but will still elaborate more.
So I am calling an API using the POST method and registering a user which gives me response data containing only the Authorization token which needs to be used while calling other APIs.

Now I want to store the token and use it in the headers while making other API calls.
I am herewith attaching a few code snippets that might demonstrate what I have done actually and what needs to be done in order to get the particular outcome.
I am getting the API response for fetching the key but I am unable to understand why it is not getting stored and why cannot I use it in the headers.

**API call that returns just the token in the response**

```
   final storage = SecureStorage();
Future<UserRegistration> registration(dynamic param) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    try {
      var response = await client
          .post(Uri.https("baseURL", "endpoint"),
              body: param)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: TIME_CONST))
          .catchError(handleError);

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    ///////Using the flutter secure storage here to save the token

         var token = storage.writeSecureToken('key', data['key']);
          print("Token Here $token");
        return UserRegistration(
          key: data['key'],
          status: true,
        );
      } else {
        print("Something went wrong");
        return param;
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('message', 'url');
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw ApiNotRespondingException("message", "url");
    }
  }
```

**API response that I am getting**

```
Response Body: {"key":"8fb303212871a80899f0b883f3554b189fddf24b"}
```

**API call that I am making which requires the Authorization Header as the key received in the previous response.**

```
Future<PhoneOTPValidate> phoneOTPvalidate(dynamic param) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var token = storage.readSecureToken('key');
    try {
      var response = await client
          .post(
              Uri.https("baseURL", "endpoint"),
              headers: <String, String>{
                'Authorization': 'Token $token',
              },
              body: param)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: TIME_CONST))
          .catchError(handleError);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return PhoneOTPValidate(
          status: data['success'],
          validate: true,
        );
      } else {
        print("The OTP is not valid");
        return param;
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('message', 'url');
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw ApiNotRespondingException("message", "url");
    }
  }
```

**My Classes for the above API calls are here:**

```
class PhoneOTPValidate {
  PhoneOTPValidate({this.status, this.validate});
  final String? status;
  final bool? validate;
}

class UserRegistration {
  UserRegistration({this.key, this.status});
  final String? key;
  final bool? status;
}
```

**Flutter Secure Storage Class**

```
class SecureStorage {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  Future writeSecureToken(String key, String value) async {
    var writeData = await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
    print('Token Here');
    return writeData;
  }

  Future readSecureToken(String key) async {
    var readData = await storage.read(key: key);
    return readData;
  }

  Future deleteSecureToken(String key) async {
    var deleteData = await storage.delete(key: key);
    return deleteData;
  }
}
```

**Here's the output for what I have written:**

```
Response Body: {"key":"de18d1239ed0b6be13f4c9a9d96eebeb1c401922"}
I/flutter (23010): Token Here Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (23010): Token Here
```

How do I solve this problem of saving the key and using it in the headers of the other API calls?
Have almost tried all the solutions from StackOverflow but nothing gave a solid answer to how it is being done.
Am stuck at this problem for quite a few days
Would appreciate it if anyone can solve my problem considering my code.

Comment: First of all, please start with descripting which step of the flow is failing?  Do you successfully receive the token? Do you store it? Can you retrieve token from storage? Do you pass it to auth header? Does API call work, if so, what's the response?

I'd throw a wild guess. Are you sure your authorization header is correct? Check if really is `'Authorization': 'Token $token'` or `'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'`.

Comment: So, I am getting the token in response. I am failing to understand that whether I am properly storing the token and using it in the proper way

Comment: I am sure that I am not using the properly using the token in the header. Because the API call that I am making using the token is not getting executed.

Comment: And it is 'Authorization' : 'Token $token'

Comment: to understand if you are storing token and if you have it in further steps, do debugging. either with debugger and breakpoints, or simply with print(token) everywhere where you are supposed to have it.

Comment: I tried to print the token after saving it in flutter_secure_storage.
But I guess it is not storing the token.
I made few code edits that might you understand what exactly I did and where is it going wrong

Comment: Bro, you need to optimize your code and do it more clear, because of that your problem seems some complex but it is (apparently) simple. Next you need to identify what's your major problem either to store your Key or to pass that Key to your next HTTP requests, because they are two questions apart. Moreover, the API server is the one that determines how to accept API requests (the syntax), so you need to read its API doc first. Then, make calls on your terminal or POSTMAN, if all works OK, just code it.

Comment: MY problem is how do I pass the key to other HTTP requests.
I have read the API documentation and it requests 'Authorization': 'Token keyvalue' in the header

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I added what exactly I am looking for

Comment: Hi @Robo.
I'm not sure but seems that your `writeSecureToken(String key, String value)` call is returning a Future<dynamic> instance and not a Map<String, String> as you expect. So, maybe you should try to resolve this Future<dynamic> to get its value.
It had been a year time since I'm not working with Flutter, and I might be a bit outdated. I think I can't help too much. Sorry.

Comment: I will suggest you try using sharedPreferences for storing the `key`. Also, try to make all your methods statically typed; for example, you can make the response type of the function `readSecureToken` Future<String>, this will make sure the function is type-safe making it easier to debug.

Comment: Firstly, I don't want to use sharedPreferences.

Comment: I don't understand why is the response key not getting stored in the flutter_secure_storage.

Comment: I wanted to understand where am I exactly getting this wrong. I wanted of you could review the code for the problem, to better understand where am I getting this wrong @JohnOyekanmi

Comment: It seems the answer provided by @Maksim Nikolaev has solved your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't "await" for secure token to be read and written. This can easily be avoided by providing explicit types for you variables. Let's fix your code:

// I assume you are using null-safety

```
class SecureStorage {
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  Future<void> writeSecureToken(String key, String value) async {
    // I'm not exactly sure how you get the data from storage.write, because it has a type of Future<void>
    // So the whole function should be await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
    await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String?> readSecureToken(String key) async {
    return await storage.read(key: key);
  }

  Future<void> deleteSecureToken(String key) async {
    // Same here: delete is a type of void, so it shouldn't return anything
    await storage.delete(key: key);
  }
}
```

Then with updating secured storage finished we can move to getting the token

```
final storage = SecureStorage();
Future<UserRegistration> registration(dynamic param) async {
  var client = http.Client();
  try {
    var response = await client
        .post(Uri.https("baseURL", "endpoint"), body: param)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: TIME_CONST))
        .catchError(handleError);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      ///////Using the flutter secure storage here to save the token
      String? token = data['key'];
      if (token == null) {
        throw Exception("No token in response");
      }
      
      await storage.writeSecureToken('key', token);
      print("Token Here $token");
      return UserRegistration(
        key: token,
        status: true,
      );
    } else {
      print("Something went wrong");
      return param;
    }
  } on SocketException {
    throw FetchDataException('message', 'url');
  } on TimeoutException {
    throw ApiNotRespondingException("message", "url");
  }
}
```

and finally fix the read for the token when you make a call:

```
Future<PhoneOTPValidate> phoneOTPvalidate(dynamic param) async {
  var client = http.Client();
  // Added type String? on the left side and await keyword for the storage.read()
  String? token = await storage.readSecureToken('key');
  if (token == null) {
    throw Exception("No token stored in storage");
  }
  try {
    var response = await client
        .post(
          Uri.https("baseURL", "endpoint"),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Authorization': 'Token $token',
          },
          body: param,
        )
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: TIME_CONST))
        .catchError(handleError);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return PhoneOTPValidate(
        status: data['success'],
        validate: true,
      );
    } else {
      print("The OTP is not valid");
      return param;
    }
  } on SocketException {
    throw FetchDataException('message', 'url');
  } on TimeoutException {
    throw ApiNotRespondingException("message", "url");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Maksim Nikolaev